# How to get an a Task similar to what StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync() returns but not started by default?

Tags: c#, file-io, task-parallel-library, streamreader

I am using a `System.IO.StreamReader` returned by `System.IO.File.OpenText(string path)` to yield an asynchronous full text file reading `Task` via its `Task<string> ReadToEndAsync()` method;

As far as I can see it returns a started task, much like `TaskFactory.StartNew(...)`;

What might be some nice ways to get a `Task` identical by the result it produces though dormant until started a more explicit way?

Comment: The task it retruns is not like `StartNew`, doing `StartNew` will start a new thread. `ReadToEndAsync` is much closer to returning something similar to a [`TaskCompletationSource<T>.Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449187(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to do this is to use a `Func<Task<String>>` delegate to defer the starting of the task.

```
public Func<Task<string>> ReadToEndLater(string path)
{
    return async () => 
    {
        using(var file = System.IO.File.OpenText(path))
        {
            return await file.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Used like

```
var readLater = ReadToEndLater(somePath);
//do stuff

var someText = await readLater();
```

The task does not get started (in fact nothing inside the `=> { ... }` gets executed) until you call `()` on the returned delegate.